# Не могу понять как написать код в питоне

Tags: python

Дан список выручки по датам

```
а = {'01.12.22': 12000, '02.12.22': 14500, '03.12.22': 18542' и тд}
```

Нужно написать функцию `summa` и на выходе получить даты через запятую, в которые выручка составила менее суммы, которую указал пользователь.
Вывод должен выглядеть так: `(f'Список дней, в которые заработали менее {sum} рублей: {summa(sum)}')`

Код который мучал я:

```
def summa(sum):
    k = a.keys()
    count = 0
    for date in a:
        for i in a:
            if i[date] > sum:
                count += 1
    return k
```

Comment: `sum` - это имя стандартной функции. Лучше использовать какое-то другое.

Comment: Вы получили ответы на прошлые вопросы, но не приняли их. Вряд ли стоит отвечать человеку, который так себя ведёт.

Comment: *«Дан список выручки по датам»* - это не список, а **словарь**.

Answer (score 1):

```
def summa(receipts, limit):
    total = 0
    days = []
    for date, value in receipts.items():
        if value < limit:
            total += value
            days.append(date)
    return days, total

# Тест с каким-то словарем и каким-то пределом
a = {'01.12.22': 10_000, '02.12.22': 20_000, 
     '03.12.22': 40_000, '04.12.22': 30_000}

days, total = summa(a, 35_000)
print(f"{days}: {total}")
```

---

*Вывод:*

> ```
> ['01.12.22', '02.12.22', '04.12.22']: 60000
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вот решение вашей проблемы

```
dict_ = {'01.12.22': 12000, '02.12.22': 14500, '03.12.22': 18542}  # ваш словарь
s = int(input('Ввод суммы пользователем: '))  # вводим сумму

def summa(d, s):
    answer = [0]  # результативный массив. 0 - место, в котором будет собираться сумма
    for key, value in d.items():  # проходим по всем элементам массива (ключам и их значениям)
        if value < s:  # если попали под ваше условие
            answer[0] += value  # увеличиваем на эту сумму нулевое значение
            answer.append(key)  # добавляем эту дату
    return answer
        
array = summa(dict_, s)
print(f'Список дней, в которые заработали менее {s} рублей: {array[0]}')
print(array[1:])  # вывод массива со срезом собранной суммы
```

Comment: Зачем это `answer[0] += value`, если это по условию вообщ не требуется и нужен просто список дней

Comment: Не сильно однозначное условие. Можно и без нулевого элемента в массиве, алгоритм не сильно поменяется.

Answer (score 0):

Если требуется просто вывести список дат, то можно через генераторное выражение:

```
a = {'01.12.22': 10_000, '02.12.22': 20_000, 
     '03.12.22': 40_000, '04.12.22': 30_000}

sum = 35000
g = (k for k, v in a.items() if v < sum)
print(f'Список дней, в которые заработали менее {sum} рублей:{list(g)}')
```

Либо в виде ленивой функции:

```
def get_date_list(d: dict, s):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if v < s:
            yield k

print(f'Список дней, в которые заработали менее {sum} рублей: {list(get_date_list(a, sum))}')
```